# C - Function that executes a command

Tags: c, ubuntu, operating-system

How does one create a function that takes another command as an argument and executes that command. For example say I wanted to do

```
./func1 cat /etc/motd
```

and have it execute the *cat* command on the file /etc/motd so that it would print the message of the day. If someone could show me that would be much appreciated!

EDIT: I cannot use the system() call as later on I have to program a basic command shell. I just need to know how to execute commands so that when a user types in cat foo.txt it executes the command and displays the file. I guess what I'm trying to say is, how do you use execve()? What arguments go inside it?

Comment: Cheap and easy: [`system(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html).  Full control: [`fork(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), then the child calls [`execve(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) (or another function from the `exec*` family), while the parent calls [`waitpid(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I understand how to use fork and watpid for the parent, but could you elaborate more on how to use execve() to execute the command

Comment: Can you tell me what, specifically, you don't understand after reading the man pages?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart For example, if i do `./func1 cat foo.txt` and I have `main(int argc, char *argv[])` what would be put in `execvp(?,?)` to execute the command? I understand that it should be `execvp(command, parameters)` so does that mean it would be `execvp(argv[1],argv[])`?

Answer (score 1):

Use you can use the `system` function.

---

Example:

```
system("cat foo.txt");
```

Will run this:

```
cat foo.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    size_t command_length = 0;

    if(argc < 2)
        return 0;

    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        command_length += strlen(argv[i]);

    command_length += argc - 2; // spaces between words
    command_length++;       // terminator '\0'

    char command[command_length];
    memset(command, 0, sizeof(command));

    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        strcat(command, argv[i]);

        if(i < argc - 1)
            command[strlen(command)] = ' ';
    }

    system(command);
}
```

It first determines the length of all command line parameters. After that it concatenates all command line parameters and inserts a space between each. Last but not least it calls the `system()` function with this string.

You need to use a C11 compiler with [VLA](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_Length_Array) support.

---

Here is a version without `system()`:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define MAX 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buf[MAX] = "/usr/bin/";
    size_t len = MAX - strlen(buf) + 1;

    if(argc < 2)
        return 0;

    strncat(buf, argv[1], len);
    execve(buf, argv + 1, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

This program only works under Linux. Unfortunately the `execve()` expects an absolute path. I assumed that the executable is located under /usr/bin. Additional work is necessary if that's not the case. For example you would have to examine the `$PATH` environment variable.

Comment: I like that you you got the command line, I can't use system(command), would you happen to know how to use execve() to execute the command?

Comment: I added an example that uses `execve()`.